# Using PdfStamper in loops

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to edit a single-paged pdf like following:

`loop` until all content was used{ 1. copys the first page 2. add some content }

Right now, everything is working expect when I try to close both document and stamper I get an error that the first one was already closed.

Thing is: 
if `document was closed` I can open it but there are only copies of pages, no content was added

If `stamper was closed`, the document is corrupt, but when I remove the document.NewPage() it workes, but only for the first page.

I tried creating a new instance of stamper in every iteration, but I get following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'iTextSharp.text.DocumentException' occurred in itextsharp.dll
>
> Additional information: The original document was reused. Read it
>   again from file.

I did close the stamper in every iteration, but it didn't help.

Comment: A very similar question has [recently been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44616179/1729265) by a user with a similar name...

Comment: You cannot reuse `PdfStamper` because `PdfStamper` changes the underlying `PdfReader` while you alter the content of the existing PDF. You need to create a new `PdfStamper` for every new output file. This is documented. See the FAQ entry on page 185 of [chapter 6](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf) of *ye old* iText in Action book. (Beats me why no one ever reads the documentation.)

Answer (score -1):

Both your New PdfReader() and New PdfStamper() should be inside the loop. Also, Close your PdfStamper inside the loop